# Why Chrome DevTools Network shows no response?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, fetch

I've been trying to fetch some url using Devtools 'copy as fetch' but I can see no response. If I try replay xhr, it will work. It's strange since it doesn't work for this particular site, but if I try 'copy as fetch' on some others it does bring a result.

What I'm trying to do is grab the response body and display it some other way (it's a schedling software, and I'm trying to modify the way it displays the calendar view since it displays everything together).

I have an extension that enables me to modify XMLHttpRequest so I can get the response of any XHR, but since the first async executes before I inject the script, then I'm always missing the first one.

I plan on using chrome webRequest to stop the first one and fetch it again.

manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "jobber",
    "version": "2.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "manifest_version": 2, 
    "permissions": [
        "webNavigation", 
        "webRequest", 
        "*://secure.name.com/*"
    ], 
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://secure.name.com/calendar*"],
        "js": ["contents.js"],
        "run-at": "document_start"
    }], 
    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": ["*://secure.name.com/calendar*"]
    }, 
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

contents.js

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    let s = document.createElement("script"); 
    s.textContent = overloadXHR(); 
    document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.children[0]);
    s = document.createElement("script"); 
    s.textContent = displayCalendar; 
    document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.children[0]); 
})();

function overloadXHR() {
    const text = `
        console.log(\`overriding: \${Date.now()}\`); 
        const rawOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open; 
        let json = []; 
        (function(){ 
            XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
                this.addEventListener("readystatechange", e => { 
                    if (/secure.name.com.calendar.*?calendar=true/i.test(this.responseURL)) {
                        if ((this.status == 200) && (this.readyState == 4)) {
                            console.log(this.readyState);
                            try {
                                json = JSON.parse(this.response); 
                                window.setTimeout(() => (window.displayCalendar({json}))({json}), 1000); 
                            }
                            catch (e) { console.log(e); }
                        }
                    }
                });
                rawOpen.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }())
    `; 
    return text; 
}
function displayCalendar({ json }) {
    // do something 
}
```

I tried POST requests too. I could see that they would work, but no response given tho.

- original request:

  [image: original request]
- copy as fetch

  [image: copy as fetch]
- copy as fetch response

  [image: copy as fetch response]
- copy as fetch timing

  [image: copy as fetch timing]

Comment: There's a typo in your manifest.json: `run-at` should be `run_at`. After fixing it your content script will run at document_start and use textContent to run the DOM script so it'll always execute before any js of the page. Another problem is that document.head won't be present at document_start so you should use document.documentElement.appendChild(s) for both scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I modified 'run-at' in manifest and it gets the first one as well. Any ideas on why I get no response from 'copy as fetch'? I can't think about any specific scenarios where I would need to get a response now, but it would help to know why there is no response body.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround to this issue is to add either:

```
.then(response => response.text()).then(console.log)
```

or

```
.then(response => response.json()).then(console.log)
```

after the `fetch` expression in the Console